# Reference a content of a type to another contant type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, entityreference

I am new to Drupal 8, and I was wondering if there is a way to link the content of one content type to another,

I have 2 content types, Article and Article_Card and I would like to make a trimmed version of each Article such as it only shows the image, title & SubTitle

Article has the following fields:

- Body
- Title
- Image
- SubTitle

If anyone can please explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reference field. On your reference field you can specify what you want to reference.

To create your trimmed version, on your field you can specify how things will be rendered. Select teaser.

On the content you're referencing, modify the teaser display with the fields you want.